# Running python in R Markdown OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, pulp, oserror

I was running an optimization process with PuLP package, the error pops up when executing the solve() function. Any idea is appreciated.

> Prob.solve()

OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Comment: This isn't much information to go on and only a very small group of people can potentially help you. Can you expand your question by giving it more "meat" so that we can at least make an educated guess? What is the code you're running? Can you make it reproducible by any chance? What have you tried to solve the problem? Just a few pointers on how to get started.